# jQuery position()/offset() value error on reload (chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I've made a menu with a backlayered moving div on hover/current menu item in wordpress.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wwv9c0v7/

Problem: Everything works fine, except when I'm reloading the page (F5). A click on a link with new page works well too. I don't know why, but the position().left returns a bad value. It's moved too far left.

```
$magicLine.css("left", $(".current-menu-item").position().left)
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: [Live preview](http://www.altefeuerwehr.de/neu/)

~ Neme

Comment: i can't replicate the scenario that you described, could you please clarify this.

Comment: The background-div of #magicline (which is in the menu as last <li>), moves on hover to left/right. If I'm clicking to different menu-item-pages, the current active menu item is the staying position on this div element. The problem is: In Google Chrome, if I'm on the (f.e.) the fourth menu page and hit F5 (reload page), the #magicline has a bad left value (wrong positioning). Does it something to do with wrong jquery caching?Just open the live preview in chrome, go to menu "anfahrt" und hit F5. Now you see the struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to see your problem, but as the documentation below refers, browsers do not expose theirs API to detect zoom situations, when you make a refresh to the page this have a different size, you can observe that behaviour when the page is loading, it begins with a different size (i assume the page comes with bigger size, because scroll bar is loaded after the page, so this makes the page to change it's size).

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/position/

Try to make this in jquery method: `$(document).ready(...)`by doing this you ensure that function will allways execute after the page is loaded.